# Problems with PHP - TPL based website after migration

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, migration, website

sorry if this question is vague, but I dont know ehere the problem is.

I just had to migrate to a new server a big, crappy website from a client, that was developed by a different company and I have almost no documentation.

The website is based on PHP, Mysql, and a TPL engine (the one from phpbb). I made sure to install the same versions of Debian, Apache, Mysql, and PHP and to copy (carefully) all configuration files.

At first it seemed to work perfectly, but then I noticed that a lot of pages that share the same TPLs were not displaying data.

For exampl, this one template does not execute anything inside the tpl tags such as this

```
!-- BEGIN titular --><!-- IF titular.HAY_IMG == '1' -->
                    <div class="titular"><img src="{repository_url}{titular.IMG}" {titular.src_edittags} alt="" /></div>
                    <!-- ENDIF --><!-- END titular -->
```

Why could this be happening? The code remains exactly the same, as does the database, the PHP, Apache and MySQL versions.

I only know very basic PHP, so its pretty difficult to me to go through the code.

So my questions:

- Has something like this happened to you before? What was the culprit?
- If the code remains the same, should I bother to go through it? In the current production server (to which I have access) its working perfectly
- I've enabled PHP error logging but I dont get any errors there, is there any other place i should look?

Please if you have any hint or idea that may help, share it, I am totally lost

Answer (score 0):

- Check your web server error logs for clues
- Does this rely on any Pear modules or other 3rd party modules?
- Is there a global config file that has hard coded paths which need updating?

Comment: -Nothing in the apache error logs.

-Not that I know of, as I dont have any documentation on the website,  but i checked all php modules installed in the previous server and installed all of them in this one. Do you know of any way to doublecheck this?

Yes there is, but I built the file structure exactly the same, and have checked all the paths repeatedly. Also, the php and tpl files ARE being used, its just that for some reason they are not being correctky executed.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions